# Change the format of date from "mm/dd/yyyy" to "Month dd, yyyy" in Ruby

Tags: ruby, nokogiri

I am trying to extract date from XML and compare it with the date in a PDF.
I am using Nokogiri to get the date from XML and PDF-Reader to read the date from PDF.

But the date in XML is in "mm/dd/yyyy" format and the date in PDF is in "Month dd, yyyy" format.

XML Tag:

```
<LetterSendDate>02/29/2016</LetterSendDate>
```

Extracting the Date from xml using Nokogiri:

```
@reader = file('C:\Users\ecz560\Desktop\30004_Standard.pdf').parse_pdf
 @xml = file('C:\Users\ecz560\Desktop\30004_Standard.xml').parse_xmlDoc
@LettersendDate = @xml.xpath("//Customer[RTLtr_Loancust='0163426']//RTLtr_LetterSendDate").map(&:text)
```

Comparing the XML date with the date in PDF:

```
 page_index = 0
 @reader.pages.each do |page|
 page_index = page_index+1
   if expect(page.text).to include  @LettersendDate
     valid_text = "Given text is present in -- #{page_index}"
     puts valid_text
   end
 end
```

but expect(page.text) returns February 29, 2016

so it is giving me error while comparing

Error

```
if expect(page.text).to include  @LettersendDate

TypeError: no implicit conversion of String into Array
```

How can I convert the date from "mm/dd/yy" format to "Month dd, yyyy format" ?